# Find occurrences of tagged items in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have this table:

```
item_id tag_id
------- ------
1       1
1       2
2       2
2       3
```

As you can probably imagine, it's a table where i have references to some items and tags that belong to them. An item can have more than one tag and one tag can be selected for more than one item.

Let's say I have also a specific tag collecion (f.ex. tag_id = 50, 73 and 119) and an "items" table with an id (referred by `item_id`).

Is there an  *efficient* query that gives me:

1. the count of items with those tags
2. the items themselves?

**What I've tried**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM items_tags it JOIN items i ON i.id = it.item_id
WHERE (tag_id=7 OR tag_id=95 OR tag_id=150) AND `status`='active'
GROUP BY item_id
) t1 WHERE c=3 <-- c= number of tags
```

I can have both results but with a very (it seems) inefficient query. After an examination with EXPLAIN, I would like to get rid of the "range" given by the ORs.

**Refining my problem:** The problem is that I was given a very poorly written PHP framework that iterates 900+ times through various tag IDs. Let's say you have one or more fixed IDs (the selected tags) and it iterates through all the 900+ tags to find the number of occurrencies of the items who have in common the given tags PLUS the iterated one (it's a function to refine the search, showing only the elements that have all the given tags plus one).

The given code works this way: I select one or more tags and their ID go into the querystring. Let's say I've selected tags 54 and 77.
The code must find every item ID for the items that have BOTH tags 54 and 77 and list them one by one: we obtain the "items with selected tags" list.

Then, it offers the choice to refine the search, and here comes the odd part: the PHP code cycles throug ALL the 900+ tags, and for every iteration it takes a tag, and counts how many items have ALL the tags 54, 77 and the one in the iteration.
If the count is > 0, it displays the name of the tag with the count number, filtering out every tag whose items don't have any link to the selected tags.

It would be nice to achieve the same result in a less "intensive" way.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: You want items that match _all_ those tags or _any_ of them?

Comment: All of them, thank you.
The output I expect is in the first case a single number of the items matching all the tags, in the second question the rows of the "items" table with the id's matching the item_id's that have all the tags.

Comment: Then my modified answer should help you out.  Is it efficient enough for your purposes?

Comment: @PinnyM: Not sure. It is in some ways similar to what I've done (nice tip for HAVING clause, though). I was suspecting of a more efficient way without using IN(...) or a bunch of ORs, it seems the real bottleneck in the query efficiency is there

Comment: @Cranio: do you have an index on this column?  If so, an IN() with 3 elements should be pretty fast. Using EXPLAIN can help you out here.  If you need to match on 3 specific values there isn't really a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: @PinnyM: The problem is that I was given a very poorly written PHP framework that iterates 900+ times through various tag IDs. Let's say you have one or more fixed IDs (the selected tags) and it iterates through all the 900+ tags to find the number of occurrencies of the items who have in common the given tags PLUS the iterated one (it's a function to refine the search, showing only the elements that have all the given tags plus one).

Comment: @Cranio, can you give a clearer example of what queries are being generated and why this function is being used?

Comment: @PinnyM: I tried to refine my answer a bit, I fear my poor knowledge of English prevents me to elaborate in a clearer way. Anyway, look above and thanks anyway for your efforts.

Comment: @Cranio: so you would need a query that returns many counts - one for each of the remaining tags when combined with the selected tags.  Is that right?  Also, is there a table that contains a comprehensive list of available tag_ids?

Comment: @PinnyM: yes, more or less it's what I want and yes, there is such a table (only tag id and name).

Answer (score 3):

To get the list of item ids that match *all* the tags, you can use this query:

```
SELECT items.id
FROM items
JOIN items_tags ON items.id = items_tags.item_id
WHERE (items_tags.tag_id IN (7,95,150))
  AND (items.status = 'active')
GROUP BY items.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT items_tags.tag_id) = 3
```

Note that if you are sure that you never have duplicate tags for the same item, you can substitute `COUNT(DISTINCT items_tags.tag_id)` with `COUNT(*)` for efficiency.

To get a count of these items, wrap this in a COUNT query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT items.id
  ...
) t
```

To get a list of the items, wrap it in this SELECT query:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT items.id ...
)
```

**UPDATE**

To get the item counts for each of the remaining tags when combined with the original list, you can do this:

```
SELECT tag_id, COUNT(DISTINCT item_id)
FROM items_tags
WHERE item_id IN (
  SELECT items.id
  ...
)
  AND tag_id NOT IN (7,95,150)
GROUP BY tag_id
```

Comment: Is DISTINCT necessary if it's on the id column of the table? Of course, that's assuming id is the primary key of the table.

Comment: @AaronHathaway: I modified my answer to reflect that the OP appears to want items that match _all_ tags.  To answer your question, yes you would need DISTINCT or you'll have multiple rows returned - one for each tag that is associated with the item.